# Что именно имеется ввиду под "WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred"

Tags: java, рефлексия, warning

```
package graphic.tests.newCollection;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class NewCollection extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        Integer ik = 5;
        Field field = ik.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(field.get(ik));
    }
}



5
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by graphic.tests.newCollection.NewCollection (file:/I:/Рабочий%20стол%20(на%20в%20данный%20момент)/Graffic%20Tests/out/production/Graffic%20Tests/) to field java.lang.Integer.value
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of graphic.tests.newCollection.NewCollection
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Решил практиковаться по рефлексии, получил вот такой вот странный результат.
речь о всех красных строк в консоли.

Помогите понять, что тут не так? прочитал некоторые подобные темы, но по сути ничего толком не понял.

Ну вопрос возник особенно на основе того, что не всегда данные предупреждения выводятся на консоль. К примеру, пробовал для вне стандарт библиотеки класса - нет предупреждений. Решил попробовать поэксперементировать с произвольным классом стандартной библиотеки, и тут получил такие строки...

дополнительно: Если я правильно понял, то с версии java 10 Рефлексия уже с капризами работает?

причина возникновения моего вопроса несмотря на осознание, что рефлексия нарушает стремления джава языка обеспечивать максимальную безопасность - является формулировка ниже в скрине.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подробности по этой ссылке https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/513-reflection-api-refleksija-temnaja-storona-java

Comment: Скорее всего ты прав! Уже с капризами! Есть вариант убрать варнинги.Там все описанно: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-7BB28E4D-99B3-4078-BDC4-FC24180CE82B

Comment: Пожалуйста, прилагайте отформатированный код / текст сообщений, а не снимки экрана. Работать с ними почти невозможно.

Comment: @hinotf сделал.

Comment: Использования рефлексии стоит избегать, о чём виртуальная машина и предупреждает.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev А в чем причина? Ну как то интересно получается, добавили возможность, которую запрещают использовать. Напрашивается вопрос: тогда в чем был смысл вообще его добавлять?

Comment: @RubenKubalyan рефлексия - это чёрных ход в JVM, нивелирующий половину достоинств языка Java. Рефлексивный код медленный и небезопасный. Применять рефлексию допустимо только при разработке инструментальных средств и фреймворков и даже при этом стоит стремиться сократить обращение к ней. Если использовать аналогию, питаться вы можете и через капельницу, но делать этого не стоит.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я обновил свой вопрос, и добавил инфо о том, из за чего у меня возник вопрос выше.

Comment: ну со стандартным библиотекой ну да ладно. А что, если включить другие библиотеки и там такая проблема, которая описана выше в скрине вопроса?

Comment: Вот из-за подобных учебных материалов, как на приведённом вами скрине, учащих плохому, в мире существует такое огромное количество кода, использующего рефлективные костыли, что разработчикам JVM пришлось добавить вывод предупреждения.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Хорошо. Больше нет вопросов.